# Why the if (find == A[i]) in SearchBack isn't giving true except first time?on debugging it clearly didnt work except for first time

Tags: c++

Why doesn't `if(find == A[i])` in `SearchBack` evaluate to true except for the first time?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int Count(int find, int A[], int size);
bool SearchBack(int A[], int size, int find, int in);

int main()

{
    int A[25] = 
    { 1,2,1,85,14,7,2,2,14,200,7,62,7,19,19,200,17,2,19,20,85,44,63,7,63 }, Q;
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        Q = 0;
        Q = Count(A[i], A, 25);
        if (Q != 0)
        {
            cout << A[i] << " : " << Q << endl;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
}

int Count(int find, int A[], int size)
{
    int counter = 0;
    bool N;
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
       if (find == A[j])
       {
            N = SearchBack(A, 25, A[j], j - 1);
            if (N == false)
            {
                counter++;
            }
            else
               return counter;
        }
        return counter;
     } 
 }

bool SearchBack(int A[], int size, int find, int in)
{  
    for (int i = 0; i <= in; i++) 
    {
        if (find == A[i])
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please have a look at how badly the code is rendered. Your formatting is wrong, edit your question and fix it please. Hint: just higlight a block of code and press Ctrl-K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things that you should change :

In `SearchBack()` you return as soon as `find` is different to `A[i]` and don't wait to see if there are occurrences of `find` after the first element of `A`. Do this instead :

```
for (int i = 0; i < in; i++)  
    {  
        if (find == A[i])  
            return true;  
    }  
return false;
```

Then, in `Count()`, you do the same kind of mistake : as soon as `N` is `true` you return, and `counter` can not increment more than once. Put `return counter` outside the `for` loop.

Last, in `SearchBack()` you want `j - 1` as stop condition but instead the current position of the element being treated in the `main()` function. You could for example pass `i` to `Count()` and then `Count()` can pass it to `SearchBack()` :

```
// in main
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        Q = 0;
        Q = Count(A[i], A, 25, i);
...

// in Count, the current_element correspond to the 'i' above
N = SearchBack(A, 25, A[j], current_element);
...
```

This way, you will print the elements of `A` only once, with the exact number of occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

Based on "Why doesn't if(find == A[i]) in SearchBack evaluate to true except for the first time?".

There is no problem in the SearchBack() func. In `count()` function I see you have placed `return counter` inside for loop after if condition which terminates the loop in the first iteration only.

Just put the return statement after for loop:

```
int Count(int find, int A[], int size) {

    int counter = 0;

    bool N;

    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)

     {
        if (find == A[j])

            {
                N = SearchBack(A, 25, A[j], j - 1);

                if (N == false)
                    {
                        counter++;
                    }
                else
                    return counter;
            }
    }
    return counter;

}
```